# dir(myFiles{m}) does't work MATLAB

Tags: matlab

`myFiles = 1x7 cell`

when I try

```
for m =1:numel(myFiles  )
    fil{m} = dir(myFiles {m});
    fil{m}.bytes ;
end
```

This is not working 
I got the error :
function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Comment: what is the content of `myfiles`? are you sure you want to use `dir`? Because you'r loop doesn't make any sense to me. type `dir(pwd)` to see what `dir` is actually doing. What do you want to do with the results? at the moment you're overwriting `fil` after every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should mention the error message you get.

Now, besides that are some obvious problems:

```
myFiles {ii}
```

This is not valid syntax to index into a cell array. Perhaps removing the space helps.

Furthermore you loop over `m` and then use `ii` as an index.

Lastly you assign to `fil` everytime. In practice this means only the last result is stored. Perhaps assigning to `fil(m)` would suit your needs better.

Answer (score 1):

The command `dir` will show you the content of a folder. As your variable is named "myFiles" I assume it contains filenames and not foldernames. So I think you're rather looking for a loop like this:

```
for ii = 1:numel(myFiles)
   fil{ii} = which( myFiles{ii} )
end
```

which gives you an array with the full paths to your files. Or are you looking for the folders containing the files in "myFiles"? Then you can use:

```
for ii = 1:numel(myFiles)
   fil{ii} = fileparts( which( myFiles{ii} ) )
end
```

returning you the corresponding folders.

---

regarding your comments:

the existence of the files/folders in "myFiles" is the only purpose?

Then you could do that:

```
for ii = 1:numel(myFiles)
   fil(ii) = exist( which(myFiles{ii}), 'file' );
end

existMyFiles = logical(fil);
```

returning a logical array specifying the existence of your files.

Comment: dir( myFiles{ii}) gives me the file or folder

Comment: myFiles could contain diles and folders , I used dir as I want to check each file exist